# Why neo4j-admin database dump command always report parameter error?

Tags: powershell, shell, command-line, neo4j

```
Neo4j Version: 5.10
Community Edition
Java Version: 17.0.8
```

I've read the document about Neo4j's `dump` command [Back up an offline database - Operations Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/offline-backup/#offline-backup-command). I use it as the document told but it doesn't work. There's no example so I don't know how to correct it.

## Purpose

I want to dump my database named `neo4j` to local directory `D:\neo4j_library_5.10\`.

## Attempts

I've tried all the commands below, but none of them are correct.

```
neo4j-admin database dump --verbose --to-path=D:\neo4j_library_5.10\ database=neo4j

neo4j-admin neo4j dump --verbose --to-path=D:\neo4j_library_5.10\

neo4j-admin database dump --verbose --to-path=D:\neo4j_library_5.10\ --database=neo4j

neo4j-admin database dump --verbose --to-path=D:\neo4j_library_5.10\ neo4j
```

It always tells me:

```
Missing required parameter: '<database>'

Dump a database into a single-file archive.
```

Can anybody give me a correct example?

---

## Update Attemps

Then I tried this command: `neo4j-admin database dump neo4j --verbose --to-path=D:\neo4j_library_5.10\`

The error message shows:

```bash
Executing command line: D:\jdk-17.0.8\bin\java.exe -cp D:\neo4j\plugins\*;D:\neo4j\conf\*;D:\neo4j\lib\* -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=1024 -Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=256 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool database dump neo4j --to-path=D:\neo4j_library_5.10"  --verbose
Unmatched argument at index 4: ' --verbose'

Dump a database into a single-file archive.
```

Then I tried to use: `neo4j-admin database dump neo4j --to-path=D:\neo4j_library_5.10\`

The error message shows:

```bash
Unmatched argument at index 4: ''

Dump a database into a single-file archive.
```

---

Final Update:

I've figured it out. My solution is in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The database name needs to go after the `dump` command, and then all the options.
So your example would be:

`neo4j-admin database dump neo4j --verbose --to-path=D:\neo4j_library_5.10`

Comment: Thank you, but sadly it still doesn't work. The error massage: `Executing command line: D:\jdk-17.0.8\bin\java.exe -cp D:\neo4j\plugins\*;D:\neo4j\conf\*;D:\neo4j\lib\* -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=1024 -Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048` I can't finish the message in one comment, I send the rest in the next comment.

Comment: This is the rest of the error message: `-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=256 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool database dump neo4j --to-path=D:\neo4j_library_5.10"  --verbose
Unmatched argument at index 4: ' --verbose'`

Comment: the above command works, move --verbose flag to the last, I am running on linux though but it worked `bin/neo4j-admin database dump neo4j --to-path=/home/ubuntu`

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to User [jenny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11334268/jenny)'s answer! Sorry that I don't have enough reputation to upvote you.

> The database name needs to go after the dump command, and then all the options. So your example would be: `neo4j-admin database dump neo4j --verbose --to-path=D:\neo4j_library_5.10`

According to the answer, I tried to change the slash direction in my command, and it worked!

This is the final command: `neo4j-admin database dump neo4j --verbose --to-path=D:/neo4j_library_5.10`

Even if you are using Neo4j's command in Windows system, you need to use the slash in *path parameters* like it's in Linux (*e.g.,* `/var/bin/`), which is to use *slash*`/` instead of *backslash*`\`.

*E.g.,* Use `F:/test_directory/test_subdirectory/` instead of `F:\test_directory\test_subdirectory\`.